# Query, @Query, @NamedQuery : SpringBoot vs JPA performance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to optimize the response time of an endpoint. I am faced with wondering if I should invest efforts in refactoring the code to see how three different approaches perform:

1. The programmatic class `javax.persistence.Query`
2. The annotation `javax.persistence.NamedQuery`
3. The annotation `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`

As it is, we use Spring's `@Query`. And the amount of refactoring to be done makes it so that I would rather get some theoretical knowledge before diving into this.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using each of these three options?

Our stack: Postgres, EclipseLink and SpringBoot.

Answer (score 4):

The `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` annotation just offers a way of specifying queries at the entity class, instead of e.g. as part of spring-data-repository interfaces (`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`). Since it is only the location of the query definition that differs, there should not be much of a perfomance difference between the two options.

The `javax.persistence.Query` interface is used by the JPA implementations internally, so again there is not much performance to be gained by using it explicitly in own code in some way.

Before digging into that direction, the following things should be evaluated first when optimizing response times:

- query speed at the database (are indices used properly?)
- number of queries issued by the ORM (e.g. avoiding n+1 problems by specifying reasonable fetching behavior using `@EntityGraph`s)

Comment: I've already investigated and fixed the mentioned suggestions. I'm at the last stretch of trying to squeeze the most out of the application's capacity. My train of thought was along the lines of "maybe there is some repetitive work that needs to be done whenever a `Query` is used, and that the result might get cached somewhere only if using the right entry-point". One example I had in mind is the parameterized SQL string: could it be that it is cached and associated with each query during initialization, or is it recalculated on every invocation?

Comment: ok I see, well statement caching is something typically taken care of by the jdbc driver, so I'd expect that there is not much optimization potential left